# Why does this template class in a library generate linker errors when used?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, templates, linker-errors

I've got the following setup. RectangleT class defined in a header file in a library. Attempted to use the class in my main application. When linking I get an error for every function I try to call - except constructor and the GetLeft/GetTop/GetRight/GetBottom - BUT - I do get the error when calling GetWidth / GetHeight.

Here's the code I've got for a simple template class.

```
namespace My2D
{
    template <typename T>
    class MY2D_API RectangleT
    {
    public:     // Construction
        RectangleT(const T left = 0, const T top = 0, const T right = 0, const T bottom = 0)
            : m_left(left)
            , m_top(top)
            , m_right(right)
            , m_bottom(bottom)
        {
        }

        RectangleT(const RectangleT<T> &source)
            : m_left(source.m_left)
            , m_top(source.m_top)
            , m_right(source.m_right)
            , m_bottom(source.m_bottom)
        {
        }

        virtual ~RectangleT(void)
        {
        }

    public:     // Getters / setters
        T GetLeft() const { return m_left; }
        T GetTop() const { return m_top; }
        T GetRight() const { return m_right; }
        T GetBottom() const { return m_bottom; }
        T GetWidth() const { return m_right - m_left; }
        T GetHeight() const { return m_bottom - m_top; }

        void SetLeft(const T value) { m_left = value; }
        void SetTop(const T value) { m_top = value; }
        void SetRight(const T value) { m_right = value; }
        void SetBottom(const T value) { m_bottom = value; }

    protected:  // Members
        T m_left;
        T m_top;
        T m_right;
        T m_bottom;
    };
}
```

Anyone got any ideas?!

Comment: The text of the linker errors would help...

Comment: First of all, I'm assuming MY2D_API is for exporting. There is no need to export a class template, it has internal linkage. I'd recommend removing that as, even if it has no effect, it's confusing. Otherwise the class looks fine to me. I suspect it's a problem with client usage: please post error and the client code called GetWidth/GetHeight. Also, just as a pet peeve, do you need a virtual dtor? Is this class intended to be used for inheritance? I'd recommend against inheriting from RectangleT to make SuperRectangles or whatever.

Comment: You need to provide code for MY2D_API macro. Your code compiles (on 2008 express) fine without it, so the problem is probably related to that macro. AND you need to give exact linker error message. Without error message trying to help you is guessing on tea leaves.

Comment: If this class is just for Rectangle purpose, then what's the need of template for this. All class members can be either int or double

Comment: @Pardeep, how would you suggest having two different internal types without the use of templates?
@stinky472, there is a Rectangle : public RectangleT<int> definition which I've excluded, this has additional functions (such as conversion to / from a Windows RECT struct).

Comment: @Mark Ingram, My main purpose for comment is that if its just a rectangle there is no need to have template for  this class. You can just have single class having either int or double class members. Templates are helpful when there is a common functionality shared across multiple data types  which can be int, float, string or some other class

Comment: @Pardeep, thanks, I have int & double specialisations, for use in different places. I figured template would be better than duplicating the base functionality (i.e. GetLeft / SetLeft etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed compiler directive **MY2D_API** and tried your code, it works fine, see below.

Windows 7, MS VS 2010

```
int main ()
{
  My2D::RectangleT < int > rect;

  rect.SetBottom(3);
  rect.SetLeft(3);
  rect.SetRight(8);
  rect.SetTop(8);
  return rect.GetHeight();
}
```